# pyodbc.Error for Teradata connection with Visual c++ redistributable

Tags: python, windows, teradata

I have some Python code (passed to me) that use pyodbc to connect to Teradata.
It gives me an error message
pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver] (77)  Visual C++ Redistributable 2012 Update 4 required. (77) (SQLDriverConnect); [HY000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver] (77)  Visual C++ Redistributable 2012 Update 4 required. (77)')

I have windows 10 Enterprise, installed 4/2021, with 64bit operating system.

I checked the installed programs through the control panel, it listed many versions of Visual C++ Redistributable (including 2005, 2008, 2010, 2012, 2013, 2015, 2017), and I also installed the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools after getting this error.

I have Teradata Tools and Utilities -Base 16.20.29 installed.

In the ODBC Admin (32bit), I am able to set up the dsn for the Teradata DB, as the Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20 is listed in the drivers. With the configuration, I can click "test" and it is successful.

But in the ODBC Admin (64bit), I set up the dsn for the Teradata DB as well, as the Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20 is listed in the drivers. With the configuration, if I  click "test", it says  "Failed. [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver] (77)  Visual C++ Redistributable 2012 Update 4 required."

And I able to use the Teradata SQL Assistant to connect to the Teradata DB with the DSN I set up.

Why is this happening? What should I do to connect to Teradata with Python?

Comment: Sounds like maybe you have the 32-bit only (x86) version of that redistributable package installed instead of the combined 32/64-bit (x64) version. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Comment: Or modify the code to use the `teradatasql` Python driver which does not rely on ODBC or VC++ redistributable.

Comment: Thank you. with teradatasql, I am able to connect to Teradata without a problem.

Comment: Thank you, Fred. the teradatasql can help me to connect to Terdata without error. I also checked the redistributables: for Visual C++2012 Redistributabale,, I have both x64 and x86; for 2015, I have only x86; for 2017 I have only x64.